# Jayway's JsonPath returns empty array if key in the predicate is not present in JSON Data

Tags: java, jsonpath

**Problem:** I am trying evaluate a JSON text using the expression

```
$.sessions[?(@.key=='session3')].value
```

using Jayway JsonPath 2.2.0 library.

```
JsonText = {
"username": xyz,
"empid": "1",
"sessions": [{
             "key": "session1",
             "value": "java"}, 
             {
             "key": "session2",
             "value": "C"}]
}
```

It return empty object instead of null even if I am using `Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL0.`

**Code snippet:**

```
Configuration configuration = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL);
Object res = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(JsonText).read("$.sessions[?(@.key=='session3')].value");
```

As it is empty object, application is unable to determine whether it's value is empty or the key itself is not present. Please help

**Note:**

`Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL` returns `null` object (as expected) if the expression is `$..sessiontype` or `$.sessions.sessiontype`